# How to plot graph for the output keeping first col as labels and 2nd col as values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

```
x2 = x1.head(10)
x2

output:
374661.0    15942
313131.0    11796
296016.0    10190
267708.0     9246
306726.0     5556
321531.0     4982
307566.0     4132
274869.0     3714
278523.0     3344
300258.0     3280
Name: UserId, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please specify which kind of plot you require (Bar, Histogram, Scatter..). And also add what you've tried..

Answer (score 0):

Here's code for Bar Graph plot :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.columns = ['labels','values']

print(df)
plt.bar(df['labels'].astype(str),df['values'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output image]

Comment: without using clipboard can I plot the graph? I mean as for clipboard recent copied item must be the data. Is it possible to convert output into new dataset?

Comment: Yes! Yes! That's what you have to do. instead, use your own data frame.